# Cross Domain AJAX Request IE Issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

```
if($.support.opacity == false && window.XDomainRequest) {
      var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
      alert(ajaxStatusUrl);
      xdr.open("get", ajaxStatusUrl);
      xdr.onload = function () {
        alert(1);
        var JSON = $.parseJSON(xdr.responseText);
        if(JSON == null || typeof(JSON) == undefined) {
          JSON = $.parseJSON(data.firstChild.textContent);
        }
        processData(JSON);
      };
      xdr.send();
    }
    else {
      alert(2);
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: ajaxStatusUrl,
        processData: true,
        data: {},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
          processData(data);
        }
      });
    }
```

Have a couple of issues
1. In browserstack IE 9 $.support.opacity is alerting to be true when it should be false
2. Major issue when I run the code in IE 7 or 8 the xdr.onload function does not fire.

Please not the header in the backend is set to allow from any origin.

Can I get some help with the cross domain requests via ajax please

Comment: *"In browserstack IE 9 $.support.opacity is alerting to be true when it should be false"* http://caniuse.com/css-opacity looks like it should be `true` to me.

Comment: I was following this documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

Comment: right, that doesn't mention the version of IE like it should. It does however mention that `$.browser` is depreciated (and now is removed) in more recent versions.

Comment: yes $.browser is deprecated and hence I am using $.support however do you have any insight on why the xdr call is not happening

Comment: I do not, i don't have a lot of experience in making them. I do know there are plugins that implement it as a transport within jquery's $.ajax method.